# Should I use presentViewController to go back to the first view controller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

Using storyboard, I present SecondViewController from FirstViewController modally. Then, I present the ThirdViewController modally from SecondViewController. I need ThirdViewController to go back to FirstViewController after selecting a `UITableViewCell`. I achieved this by using the following code.

```
  let firstViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstViewController") as! FirstViewController
  self.present(firstViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However, I just now realize this may not be the best practice because this will add another ViewController on the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's better to use NavigationViewController and push and pop among your viewControllers.

Comment: This is what I am thinking as well, but want to make sure I am not overthinking this.